# Clear container to take photographs through

Tags: reflection

Is there any type of clear container that objects inside can be photographed with little to know effect.  As in, photographing the object inside the container at different angles is the same (or almost) as outside of the container.

Something like glass has reflections, so it  would seem to only work with the lens flat against the glass, except even then other sides may contain reflections.

I am imagining this for something such as a live butterfly that I would want to be able to contain for a short time in order to photograph it.  Does this exist?

Comment: You could just get a circular polariser to eliminate the reflections on any non-metallic object...

Comment: Polarizers are not 100% effective, unfortunately, although it can get a LOT better with one. However, to get the reflection-reducing effect at all you have to shoot at a particular angle to the reflecting surface plusminus not a lot. It is not a panacea.

Answer (score 3):

This is the classic problem faced by aquarium owner attempting to photograph their fish. So yes, an aquarium is what you want.

Clear the front glass perfectly, dust, water spots, etc, will really show up in the photograph. Use a lot of bright light above the tank.

Now, to eliminate reflections on the front glass get a dark blanket and tape it to the top of the tank and get under it. Wear a dark shirt and if you don't have dark hair, wear a dark hoodie.

There will still be some reflections off the camera lens, so never shoot straight through the glass, always shoot at an angle.